# how to bring an element to the bottom of a division?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header `div` that contains logo and a navigation menu
Lets say I have a logo on the left hand side `100x50` and a navigation menu that should `float: right`

How do I get the navigation menu to align just above the base of the header div?
What happens if the logo size changes, can it be done with respect to the logo size without having to adjust the `margin-top` for the `nav` element?
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="site-logo">
        </div><!-- /site-logo -->

        <nav class="site-nav">
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.site-header nav ul {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

div.site-logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

P.S.: If it can be done without javascript, it would be nice

[image]

Comment: If you change the logo size then you have to change the css so you could alter any nav margin at that point - or, the nav could be absolute and tied to the bottom & right of the header so no matter how high the logo, your nav will always be in the same place

Comment: @DarrenSweeney can you please give me an example code for it on how to position it to the bottom right of the header with absolute

Comment: Added answer @JeffreyChen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give you an example with flexbox. It's way much easier than with position absolute, and you don't need to worry about the logo size.

```css
.site-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

div.site-logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00f;
}

div.site-nav {
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #f00;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="site-logo"></div><!-- /site-logo -->

        <div class="site-nav"></div>
    </header>
</div>
```

If you use flex, you may need to add the property names for other browser.

Answer (score 0):

To use absolute positioning for your nav, your header needs relative positioning:

`header { position: relative; }`

then something like:

```
.site-header nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px; /* or whatever you choose */
  bottom: 5px; /* or whatever you choose */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way how to implement it: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/romfrolov/7ruLutL3/)

```
.site-header {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

div.site-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.site-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 4.2vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To align something to the bottom of an element, set the `position` of that thing to `absolute` and it's `bottom` coordinate to `0`, so that there will be zero pixels between that thing and the bottom border of the containing element.

```
.site-header nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;          // Aligned to parent's bottom border...
  right: 0;           // ...and parent's right border.
}
```

Note that you can position something absolutely only in a positioned parent, either absolutely:

```
.site-header {
   position: absolute;
}
```

...or relatively, where you have make sure to enforce a Block Formatting Context (BFC) to hold your contents (logo + menu), typically by specifying the `overflow` behavior of your relative parent to anything but `visible`:

```
.site-header {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;   // Enforce BFC
}
```

Here is a pure CSS [demo](https://codepen.io/Javarome/pen/KaLeZq) that shows that it will fit any logo size.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `flex`. The simplest approach is to add `padding` for the `nav` element.

```
padding top
    +
nav height
    +
padding top
```

the total height equal to the height of the header bar.